# Misconfigured Azure SSO for admin.google.com

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, google-workspace

I accidentally misconfigured the Azure SSO settings for the login at admin.google.com and now get always redirected to the MS365 login that is not working of course.

Is there any way to get access again? I only have one account for admin.google.com :/

Thanks!

Best,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you configure a third party IdP SSO in the Admin console the super admins automatically do a bypass as stated in the official [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6341409?hl=en&ref_topic=7556907#:%7E:text=Signing%20in%20with%20super,SSO%20sign%2Din%20page.).

[image]

In case you are the only super admin and you are not bypassing the SSO for some reason, you can ask for support by filling out this [form](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/recovery/form). If I'm not mistaken you have to follow a proces to verify that you are the owner of the domain by adding a TXT or CNAME record and then they provide you access again.

There is more information about account recovery [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561).